# How to abort iOS Alamofire Multipart Upload on failure in encoding

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have implemented a working multipart upload on iOS using Alamofire. However from time to time an error occurs during the creation of the multipart upload. I would like to handle that error gracefully (currently it calls `fatalError` and crashes the whole app. I would rather like to do something like throwing and aborting the upload.

Some pseudo code as explanation.

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {data in 
    if self.create() == .failure {
        throw error
    },
    usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), 
    to: url, 
    method: .post, 
    headers: headers, 
    encodingCompletion: {error in
        self.onEncodingComplete()}
)
```

Of course this `throw` does not work, since the closure is not throwing. Does anyone have a working solution for this?

Comment: Could you show the error message when it fails?

Comment: There is no error message, except the one I provide when calling `fatalError()`. That is exactly the problem. I am unable to abort the upload upon a failure during encoding. There is no hook I can use. If encoding fails, Alamofire sends an incomplete multipart request.